# Ordered dictionary returned as [0] from Function

Tags: powershell, foreach, ordereddictionary

[ordered dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70974411/regular-expression-only-finding-first-match?noredirect=1#comment125471573_70974411)

I have some code that returns an ordered dictionary, and all looks good when I return it in the function, but on the receiving end, it is all showing up in [0] of the data structure.

This is the Function:

```
function Get-Contents60{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param ([string]$fileContent)

    # create an ordered hashtable to store the results
    $errorMap = [ordered]@{}
    # process the lines one-by-one
    switch -Regex ($fileContent -split '\r?\n') {
        'MAKEWORD\([^,]+,([^)]+)\),' { # seJam, seFatal etc.
            $key = $matches[1]
        }
        '(HOP_[^)]+)' {
            $errorMap[$key] = $matches[1].Trim()
        }
    }
    # output the completed data as object
    [PsCustomObject]$errorMap
    return $errorMap
}
```

This is what it looks like in $errorMap:

```
> [Ordered Dictionary: 69] [0]: [seFatal, "Hop_Error" [1]: [seInterface,
> "Hop_Interface" ...
```

It is received in the main code like this:

```
$HopResultMap = [ordered]@{}
$HopResultMap2 = [ordered]@{}
$HopResultMap = (Get-Contents60 -fileContent $matchFound)
```

But the $HopResultMap data has changed at this point and looks like this:

```
Object[2]:
[0]: @{seFatal = HOP_Error; seInterface = HOP_Interface; ...}
[1]: Ordered Dictionary:69
```

So when I try to get the data out, I'm unable to access the key, and use it to get data from the next map.

```
  #combine the maps so can reuse 7000's case/design.  
  $resultCase = foreach ($key in $HopResultMap){
    $tmpDesc = (HopResultMap2[$key] -split '-')[-1] #take part after -
    $tmpSdkErr = (HopResultMap2[$key] -split '-')[0] #take part before  -
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
      sdkErr      = "$($tmpSdkErr)" #after test this, use split directly
      sdkDesc     = "$($tmpDesc)" #after test this, use split directly
      sdkOutErr   = $HopResultMap[$key]
    }
  }
```

Where each $key in $HopResultMap part isn't actually returning the key (ex, first is $seFatal).

Why is this data structure not being received in a usable format?  How would I fix that?  I tried adding the $HopResultMap = [ordered]@{} where I didn't define it before in the main code, but the returned map still gets moved into length 2, with the map being in the first element.

This is using powershell 5.1 and VSCode.

I've tried changing the code to

```
        $resultCase = foreach ($key in $HopResultMap[1]){
            $tmpDesc = (HopResultMap2[$key] -split '-')[-1] #take part after -
            $tmpSdkErr = (HopResultMap2[$key] -split '-')[0] #take part before  -
            [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
              sdkErr      = "$($tmpSdkErr)" #after test this, use split directly
              sdkDesc     = "$($tmpDesc)" #after test this, use split directly
              sdkOutErr   = $HopResultMap[$key]
            }
          }
```

But the key is still the entire map, and not the left side of the first one.

Comment: Your function outputs _two_ objects: first, via _implicit_ output, `[PsCustomObject] $errorMap`, and then, via `return`, `$errorMap`

Comment: so how do I do a foreach with the keys? Maybe I just never tried to do that before.

Comment: Remove the `[PsCustomObject]$errorMap` statement so that your function outputs the ordered hashtable only, then enumerate its keys with `foreach ($key in $HopResultMap.Keys) { ... }`

Comment: @mklement0 - thank you so much! I couldn't figure out why it was re-formatting! And good way to iterate over the keys.  You're the best.